# Ionic framework- e2e testing using protractor with Ios emulator

Tags: selenium, ionic-framework, protractor, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid app build with Ionic framework and would like to test on the emulator using protractor. How can I setup to run test on emulator using protractor?

Here is what I have attempted so far:

1) All my test run in the browser fine.

2) installed Appium (http://appium.io/)

3) modified my protractor.config.js file:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',

   specs: [
     'e2e/*_spec.coffee'
    ],

   capabilities: {
     browserName: '',
     'appium-version': '1.3',
      platformName: 'iOS',
      platform: 'Mac',
      platformVersion: '8.2',
      deviceName: 'iPhone 5s',
     app: 'absolute_path/platforms/ios/build/emulator/taco.app'
   },

   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100',
 };
```

This launches the emulator, however, not test are running. Here is a sample spec...

```
describe 'Taco', ->
  describe 'Login', ->
    beforeEach ->
      browser.get('http://localhost:8100')
      browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();')
      browser.waitForAngular()

    it 'should login with valid credentials', ->
      expect(element(By.css('.home-template')).isPresent()).toBe(true)

      element(By.linkText('I have an account')).click()
      element(By.model('credentials.email')).sendKeys('taco1@taco.com')
```

Comment: Are you using crosswalk as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I run an ionic app in android studio emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711120/how-do-i-run-an-ionic-app-in-android-studio-emulator)