# How do I run an ionic app in android studio emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to ionic and I want to run my app on android studio emulator. I did refer the link
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html. But I do not seem to understand how to run my ionic app on emulator

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/emulate/ or http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/run/

Answer (score 29):

First ensure that your Android Studio setup is correctly done. If want to do that from scratch refer these links - [link1](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#installing-the-requirements) and [link2](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?pkg=studio). In link2, you can choose your OS as well.

[This](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/) ionic guide will help you setup ionic project correctly. If you follow this guide entirely, you will see the use of `emulate`, `platform`, `run`, `serve`, etc commands of ionic.

Basically what you need to do is first add an android platform to your project:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

And then emulate your project using:

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

Answer (score 6):

You can install capacitor which created by the ionic team and i recommend it over cordova

Inside your project do this

```
ionic integrations enable capacitor
```

then

```
npx cap init [appName] [appId]
```

after that add android or ios folder to your project by this command

```
npx cap add ios
npx cap add android
```

then finaly you can run your app by

```
npx cap open ios
npx cap open android
```

or this command

```
ionic capacitor run android
```

Answer (score 4):

1. First open Android studio and start an emulator wait when its still done (first time needs more time)

   2. test if the emulator is available with `android list devices``
   3. ionic cordova emulate android will publish it on your emulator

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Android Studio you need to make at least one project and open the project, and then create AVD (android virtual device) in Tools - Android - AVD Manager, and then in your ionic project

```
ionic cordova emulate [platform]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for example :

```
ionic cordova emulate android -lcs
```

Comment: l = livereload, c = console logs, s = ?, https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/emulate/

Comment: @KimT ```s = server logs``` .. take a look : https://github.com/isathish/ionic-cli#live-reload-app-during-development-beta

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run the ionic app in emulator by first launching it from the Android Studio on Windows. Trying to run just by the command timed out.
-Start emulator from Studio (Tools | AVD Manager)
-On command line, run "ionic cordova emulate android"

Answer (score 1):

> step 1 - Create Virtual Device

- AVDs are managed with the AVD Manager. In the Android Studio welcome
  screen, click Configure » AVD Manager. The AVD Manager can also be
  opened inside Android projects in the Tools » AVD Manager menu.

> step 2 - set environment From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.->Properties -> Advanced system settings->Environment Variables->User variable ->Path->edit->New and add **your emulator path** like given below
>
> eg. C:\Users\kunal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator

then,

```
ionic cordova platform add android

ionic cordova emulate android
```

or

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not integrated capacitor to your project follow from step 1. If you have already integrated capacitor follow from step 2.
Enter below command on your command prompt.

### Step 1

***ionic integrations enable capacitor***

### Step 2

***npx cap init [appName] [appId]***

(appName is the name of your app, and appId is the domain identifier of your app (ex: com.example.app))

### Step 3

***ionic build*** - Build your application

### Step 4

***npx cap add ios*** - Copy to ios destination folder

***npx cap add android*** - Copy to android destination folder

### Step 5

***npx cap open ios***

***npx cap open android***

> If you need to run ios app on a emulator you need to have xcode in a mac device. But if you need to run it on an android emulator you need to install android studio either on ios or windows.